# HTML5/H.264 format for desktop sharing

Tags: asp.net, encoding, html, h.264, screensharing

I am trying to **live stream** my desktop over http to one or more users. The immediate goal is just to share the desktop in real time in read only mode for several users. In future we might allow the users to control the desktop as well by mouse or keyboard. I have these queries in this context-

Is HTML5 + H.264 right for this or do I need to go with Flash?

In either case what are all the components/servers I need for a live streaming infrastructure? (Like desktop, encoder, streaming server, web server, media player etc)? It will help compare the options, if You can post your preferences for each of these components/servers.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this with Flash, I don't know for sure about HTML5. In windows I should suggest you create a directshow graph to do this. You'll want a screen capture source filter, h264 encoder and a flash streaming output filter.

A directshow screen capture filter.
http://www.mainmediasoft.com/products/screencapture/

ffdshow can encode h264
http://ffdshow-tryout.sourceforge.net/

flash streaming output filter.
http://www.nanocosmos.de/v3/en/rtmp-streaming.html

In theory you should be able to drag all these parts together in graphedit and make this work.